# Embedding QR Code in a stand alone Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, qr-code

I would like to embed a QR Code on a stand-alone Crystal Report.

I'm planning to embed information from the report (like Name or Address) that will be stored in the QR that will be generated in the Crystal report.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or link to any resources explaining how to do this?

Comment: Are you proving the info or asking for the info? be specific with your explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easiest to use an on-line service.

- Insert a picture
- Edit the conditional formula associated with the picture's `Graphic Location` property
- Provide a link that will generate the QR code.  For example: `"http://www.esponce.com/api/v3/generate?content=" + {table.field} + "&format=png"`

Comment: We took a similar approach with generating barcodes because we did not want to install barcode fonts on every desktop that needed to run the report. Be warned that dynamically generating images for each QR code may not scale well. Also, know that the third party service may fail you without notice.

Comment: @SunWKim: Good point.  One could use an open-source implementation like [QRCoder](https://github.com/codebude/QRCoder), then wrap it with a REST service on a LAN.

Comment: This worked! Thanks a lot!

Btw this is the code I used.

'http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=' + {table.field1} + ',' + {table.field2}